# matplotlib warning on color_cycle

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
C:\Anaconda64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py:872: UserWarning: axes.color_cycle is deprecated and replaced with axes.prop_cycle; please use the latter.
  warnings.warn(self.msg_depr % (key, alt_key))
```

I am using the latest matplotlib version, but getting the warning above. How to fix it? The soln here suppresses all warnings: [How to suppress matplotlib warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33792478), and that is not what I want

Comment: Use `prop_cycle` instead of `color_cycle`, as suggested?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to suppress matplotlib warning?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33792478/how-to-suppress-matplotlib-warning)

Comment: @fjarri, I am not using prop_cycle, matplotlib is using it. Phiter, the soln on that page suppresses all warnings. I do not want that.

Comment: From your question it is not really clear how this warning was produced. It would be easier to answer your question if you described your scenario.